# need to select a string between two two known characters in hadoop hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

How to check only for a keyword in a string which occurs after 2nd % & before 3rd %  in hadoop hive? For eg. products%apple products%security%firewalls%adaptive security appliances (asa)%

the returning keyword should be "security"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `regexp_extract`.

Try this in Hive cli
`select regexp_extract('products%apple products%security%firewalls%adaptive security appliances (asa)%', '[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*%[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*%([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*)%.*', 1)`

Secret is in the group that you capture.

Comment: its not returning anything,the value for the row is null.

Comment: I am not sure, what you executed. I executed this in my hive console and got the appropriate output. My Hive version is 0.13.1. Have a look at this pastebin http://pastebin.com/ddDSYQg3 . Mind sharing the query?